# MySQL: InnoDB vs. MyISAM: how and why to change (Amazon RDS)?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, innodb, myisam, amazon-rds

I didn't set up my database and noticed that some of my tables are innoDB whereas others are MyISAM. The reason I'm interested in changing them is because [Jurg van Vliet](http://www.quora.com/Jurg-van-Vliet) (who writes O'Reilly books on AWS) [says](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-cons-of-hosting-a-MySQL-DB-in-Amazon-RDS-versus-a-DB-instance-in-EC2) that Amazon RDS's automatic database backup ability hinges on all tables being innoDB tables.

What's the command to convert all tables in a database to InnoDB?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a stored procedure to convert all MyISAM table in the current database to InnoDB:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS convert_all_tables_to_innodb;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE convert_all_tables_to_innodb()
DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
COMMENT ''
proc: BEGIN
    DECLARE b_not_found     BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE v_table_name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT
table_name
FROM
information_schema.tables
WHERE
table_schema = DATABASE() AND
table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND
engine = 'MyISAM'
ORDER BY
1;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET b_not_found = TRUE;

    OPEN cur1;

    SET b_not_found = FALSE;

    loop1: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO v_table_name;
        IF b_not_found THEN
            LEAVE loop1;
        END IF;

        SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', v_table_name, ' ENGINE=InnoDB');

        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DROP PREPARE stmt;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

To run it, simply execute:

```
CALL convert_all_tables_to_innodb();
```

Comment: -@Ross thanks, is there no simple SQL command for this? Also, can you explain why you switched from MyISAM to innoDB?

Comment: Sorry, but there is no single command to convert all the tables, which is what you specified in your question. I offered this code to answer your question.

Comment: -@Ross thanks, did you use this stored_procedure yourself? If so, would you mind sharing some context as to why you used it?

Comment: Tim, no I have not used this procedure as written. I *have* used similar prodedures to `ANALYSE`, or `OPTIMIZE` all tables.

Comment: -@Ross, just wanted to let you know i called this stored procedure and it worked great, all my tables are now innoDB, thanks!

Comment: Great to hear, and glad to help!